# XAMMP: как правильно создать виртуальный хост?

Tags: windows, apache, http, xampp, windows-8

Пытаюсь создать виртуальный хост на XAMPP под Windows 8. В файл C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf добавил строчки:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost mysite.dev:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/WebServers/home/mysite.dev/www"
    ServerName mysite.dev
    ServerAlias www.mysite.dev
    ErrorLog "C:/WebServers/home/mysite.dev/logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "C:/WebServers/home/mysite.dev/logs/access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

В файл C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts добавил строчку

```
127.0.0.1 mysite.dev
```

Создал папки:
C:\WebServers\home\mysite.dev\www
C:\WebServers\home\mysite.dev\logs

В папку C:\WebServers\home\mysite.dev\www положил файл index.html

Перезапустил XAMPP.

После этого пытаюсь открыть страницу http://mysite.dev/ и получаю сообщение об ошибке:

> Ваше соединение не защищено
>
> Владелец mysite.dev неправильно настроил свой веб-сайт. Чтобы защитить вашу информацию от кражи, Firefox не соединился с этим веб-сайтом.
>
> Этот сайт использует Форсированное защищённое соединение HTTP (HSTS), чтобы указать, что Firefox должен подключаться к нему только через защищённое соединение. В результате, добавление исключения для этого сертификата невозможно.

Firefox почему-то пытается открыть https, хотя я явно указываю ему http.
Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так? Может нужно ещё какие-то настройки поменять? Установка XAMPP чистая - только что установил с нуля, никаких настроек не менял.

Comment: Попробуйте из другого браузера или почистите HSTS кэш в фаерфоксе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том что Firefox и Chrome автоматически перенаправляют трафик c http:// на https:// если вы используете в качестве домена первого уровня .dev ([вот информация](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/) [и вот](https://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=47258))

Самый простой выход не использовать домен .dev

А hosts не работает потому что браузер берет из кэша dns информацию о хосте это можно отключить:

1. Открываем FF
2. вводим в адресную строку about:config
3. кликаем правой кнопкой мыши на любом свойстве выбираем New > Integer в контекстном меню
4. Вводим в имя - network.dnsCacheExpiration, значение - 0

Comment: В моём случае замена домена на mysite.localhost или на mysite.test помогла. И ведь нигде ни в сообщении об ошибке ни в документации не написано об этой особенности.